# RewriteCond to skip actual directories seems to be ignored

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, cpanel, whm

My problem is that The `RewriteRule` is still matching when I visit a physical directory, e.g. `http://a-domain.com/foo/` where `foo` is a normal directory in the web root.

the `.htaccess` file has:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .? index.php [L]
```

It works fine on my dev server but not on a live WHM/CPanel server. I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled on your shared hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this on my cpanel website and you're right and I found out where's the problem. when you try to access a folder in your website that doesn't have default file (index) , it tries to access the file that is responsible for 403 HTTP code, and because that doesn't exist, it rewrites URL to `index.php`.

All you have to do is add this to above of your `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?type=err&code=403
```

Comment: I went with just `Options -Indexes` and `ErrorDocument 403 /index.php` since I avoid modifying query parameters in `.htaccess`. That allowed access to the desired subfolder while passing folders without listing allowed through to the php.

Comment: my server generates 403 status code, that's why I put 403 in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on a [VM which mirrors my own shared service](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-61) and it works fine for me.  Have you got another `.htaccess` in the `foo` directory?  If so, then the rewrite engine will ignore your one in DOCROOT and use this instead?

Comment: Yes, but it has no `mod_rewrite` directives in it.

Comment: I guess that your (two) system/vhost configs have different `DirectoryIndex` directives.  If you have a directory index which includes index.php then the rule works but /foo/ is then mapped to /foo/index.php so it appears that the rule is firing

Comment: I'm not touching the vhost or system configs, so what would it matter if they're different? Only the one with the highest precedence would be in effect. There is a DirectoryIndex directive and it should match /foo/index.php that exists, but then why would my rule match? It has conditions so it won't match on a real dir/file/symlink.

Comment: @Walf, I was talking about the differences between the system / vhost configs of your dev server compared to your prod server.  It's well worthwhile taking a tarball of the prod /etc/(apache2|httpd) directory and doing a comparison so that you can align dev to prod or even set up a local test VM which mirrors prod more closely.  You also need be careful of subqueries polluting this.  Try adding an [NS] flag.

Answer (score 0):

The `/foo/` dir has basic authentication so it was failing when `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` contained a non-existent file `/home/the_user/public_html/401.shtml`. I didn't think this was an issue because the basic authentication worked, and when I cancelled the auth prompt I was being served a standard 401 file. Usually when those ErrorDocument files are missing, Apache says *Additionally, an error of type 404 was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*